# Difference between "include" and "-include" in a makefile

Tags: c, include, makefile

In a makefile, what is the difference in meaning between `include` and `-include`?

Examples:

```
-include $(APPINCLUDES)

include $(CONTIKI)/platform/$(TARGET)/Makefile.$(TARGET)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's hard to search for terms containing special characters. I tried a few search engines, including SymbolHound, without success. By the way, there is a typo in the link: a **"** appended at the end.

Comment: @MartinStålberg What code is compiled with gcc? As far as I understand this is GNU make.

Comment: @AymanSalah, I'm afraid I don't remember. I wrote the question 6 years ago.

Comment: Just a note. From the docs: "For compatibility with some other make implementations, `sinclude` is another name for `-include`."

Comment: @n3rd4n1, broken link. I assume you are referring to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The difference is that `-include` won't generate an error if the include file doesn't exist.

The `-` prefix can be used many places in the `Makefile` to perform actions that you don't mind if they fail.

Answer (score 10):

From the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html)

> If you want make to simply ignore a makefile which does not exist or
> cannot be remade, with no error message, use the -include directive
> instead of include, like this:
>
> -include filenames...
>
> This acts like include in every way except that there is no error (not even a warning) if any of the filenames (or any prerequisites of
> any of the filenames) do not exist or cannot be remade.